# Using Angular.js to play sound while click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using Angular.js and some Jquery to make some buttons play sound while clicked.This is the html code:

```
<audio id="audio">
    <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3"></source>
    <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3"></source>
    <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3"></source>
    <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3"></source>
</audio>
<button class='t-l bt' ng-click='play_sound(0)'></button>
<button class='t-r bt' ng-click='play_sound(1)'></button>
<button class='b-l bt'  ng-click='play_sound(2)'></button>
<button class='b-r bt'  ng-click='play_sound(3)'></button>
```

This is my function code:

```
$scope.play_sound = function(order){
      var audio = $('#audio')[order];
      audio.play();
    }
```

The function works when I 0 is passed in as argument and failed while passing other number.This is what I got in the google console:

```
angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined
    at b.$scope.play_sound (index.js:10)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:14817), <anonymous>:4:234)
    at b (angular.js:15906)
    at e (angular.js:25885)
    at b.$eval (angular.js:17682)
    at b.$apply (angular.js:17782)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:25890)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

Comment: `$('#audio')` returns a *single* element (as there is only one with that `id`) and so `$('#audio')[1]` and the rest won't work...

Comment: I think kukkuz is right, although I can't find it in the documentation. Bear in mind a jQuery object can represent more than one HTML element. So `$('#audio')[order]` as you intended it doesn't make sense, and then `[0]`, `[1]`, etc must mean the DOM elements in the jQuery object (of which there is only one). But I don't know how to change the source.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below. Idea is to get individual source file and play that audio based on order.

```
$scope.play_sound = function(order){
      var audioSource = $('#audio source')[order];
      var audio = new Audio(audioSource.attr("src");
      audio.play();
    }
```